# Python super()について

Tags: python

あるクラスを継承したクラスを作成し、イニシャライザを

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

とすることに何か意味はありますか。ここで記述される処理は、継承した時点で何を記述せずとも実行されると考えるのですが…御回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

親クラスの `__init__` をオーバーライド（上書き）してしまっているので、そのままでは子クラスで定義した `__init__` の内容しか実行されません。そのため、もし親クラスの `__init__` の処理に**追加する形で**子クラスの `__init__` を定義したいのであれば、子クラス側で親クラスの `__init__` を呼び出す必要があります。

```
class Greet():
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 'Hello!'
    def enter(self):
        print(f'{self.hello}')

class Greet2(Greet):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.bye = 'Bye!'
    def depart(self):
        print(f'{self.bye}')

dialogue = Greet2()
dialogue.enter()
dialogue.depart()
```

このコードで `super().__init__()` をコメントアウトすると

> AttributeError: 'Greet2' object has no attribute 'hello'

オーバーライドで親クラスの `__init__()` が実行されなくなっているためです。

Comment: 疑問点だけにフォーカスし、簡潔かつ正確なご説明に大変感謝します。